# Правильный подход к разработке приложений?

Tags: c#

Подскажите что можно почитать о том, как правильно разрабатывать проекты под консоль, а затем перейти на формы/другой вид проекта, чтобы сохранить саму структуру

Comment: "[Руководство Microsoft по проектированию архитектуры приложений, 2-е издание](http://download.microsoft.com/documents/rus/msdn/%D1%80%D1%8B_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0.pdf)" + [Книги и учебные ресурсы по C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/213987)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую почитать про архитектурные паттерны, в частности [MVC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller) и его популярные разновидности(в вашем случае, кмк, подойдёт MVP).
Разделите ваш проект на Бизнес логику `BL`, Доступ к данным`DA` и Представления`View`.

- Доступ к данным - это ваша основа в работе с источниками данных. Ну, РСУБД/noSQL базы данных или другие источники.
- Бизнес-логика - классы отвечающие за то, что берется из слоя `DA` и поставляется пользователю в слой `View`. 
  К примеру, класс конвертер валют, который берет данные о долларовом счете абстрактного пользователя из БД, например, и конвертирует в рубли.
- Представления - классы, отвечающие за отображение данных. Здесь может быть адаптер вывода данных на консоль, формы и прочее.

Каждую группу таких классов, желательно, конечно, реализовывать от интерфейса, для меньшей связности(cohesion). Это, позволит, в дальнейшем, подменять реализации, если вдруг такая необходимость понадобится.

Это, скажем так, стандартные слои архитектуры приложения. Если ваше приложение построено в таком формате, то вам не составит большого труда, подменить консоль на форму.

Успехов.